# How to check the VPC endpoint to ECS working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I am making VPC Endpoint to ECS.

I want to connect from `EC2` in private subnet to `ECS`

```
com.amazonaws.ap-northeast-1.ecs
com.amazonaws.ap-northeast-1.ecs-agent
com.amazonaws.ap-northeast-1.ecs-telemetry
```

At first I made VPC Endpoint to `com.amazonaws.ap-northeast-1.ecs`

`enableDNSname` is false and set subnet to my private subnet.

then made for `com.amazonaws.ap-northeast-1.ecs-agent` and `com.amazonaws.ap-northeast-1.ecs-telemetry`

Now three endpoint is created.

then I want to check the Endpoint is correctly working, so in `EC2 node` I `ping com.amazonaws.ap-northeast-1.ecs` but it returns `Name or service not known`

does it means VPC Endpoint setting is not correctly?

If so how can I check ?

(Also I wonder if I need to `enableDNSname` to access to the `ECS`?)

Comment: `enableDNSname` - yes it must be enabled.

Comment: You have to reverse the name tokens to ping an endpoint.  `com.amazonaws.ap-northeast-1.ecs` becomes `ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: This says both DNS Resolution and DNS Hostnames must be enabled in the VPC https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html

Comment: Thank you I will try with `enableDNSname`.

Comment: By the way I am doing this ping `com.amazonaws.ap-northeast-1.ecs` in the container which has NAT Gateway.  still it returns `ping: com.amazonaws.ap-northeast-1.ecs: Name or service not known` how can I confirm it is connected to?

Comment: Ah that's my mistake!! I can ping ecs.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com